# get path from JSON model

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sapui5

I already created dropdown menu. I have a problem with event press. I want get context from JSON when I press the menu.

JSON:

```
dropdownMenu: {
    kepesertaan:[
        {
            name: "Menu1",
            icon: "sap-icon://crop",
            sub: [
                { 
                    name: "Submenu1-1",
                    icon: "sap-icon://create-session"   
                },
                { 
                    name: "Submenu1-2",
                    icon: "sap-icon://create-form" 
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Menu2",
            icon: "sap-icon://detail-view",
            sub: [
                { 
                    name: "Submenu2-1",
                    icon: "sap-icon://add-activity" 
                },
                { 
                    name: "Submenu2-2",
                    icon: "sap-icon://action" 
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Menu3",
            icon: "sap-icon://delete",
            sub: [
                { 
                    name: "Submenu3-1",
                    icon: "sap-icon://add-favorite" 
                },
                { 
                    name: "Submenu3-2",
                    icon: "sap-icon://add-document" 
                }
            ]
        }               
    ]
```

}

JS:

```
        handleMenuItemPressKepesertaan: function(oEvent) {
            var app = sap.ui.getCore().byId("menuEventingKepesertaan");
            var oModel = app.getModel("kepesertaanmodel");
            var oContext = oModel.getProperty("/1"); // get context from property by path
            alert(oContext.name);
//          alert(oContext.sub[0].name);

            var bindingContext = sap.ui.getCore().getBindingContext();
            var path = bindingContext.getPath();
            alert(path);
        }
```

I tried and alert path but failed. getPath() is not a function or undefined.
and this path will change the code "var oContext = oModel.getProperty("/1");". value "/1" is a path. and how to fix this problem? for information, the menu in fragment xml.

Comment: add your code in  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so its easy to solve the problem

Comment: how to create xml? I using xml code

Comment: var bindingContext = oEvent.getBindingContext(); try this you might find a solution

Comment: an you paste your xml fragment? As it will answer the qurstions such as 1. are you using named model? 2. The event is applied to dropdown or at item level ? 3. the control ( sap.m or sap.ui)